# Drupal 7 Hierarchtical Taxonomy Translations

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I currently have hierarchical select installed but on the pages it's it doesnt apply basic localization. I need it to use the translations i have set up in the translation database of drupal. I have searched around google but havn't had luck finding a working solution.

Any help appriciated, thanks!

Comment: r u using Internationalization module?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Taxonomy translation module (Comes inbuilt with the Internationalization module).

If you are not using Internationalization module, please do make use of it to translate the taxonomy related values.

Comment: Taxonomy Translation is enabled. Yet it is not being translated

Comment: Ok. Please visit admin/structure/taxonomy and then click the 'edit' for the taxonomy for which you want the translation to happen. Now you can see a option called 'Multilingual option'. Enable 'Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated'. This will make the terms in this vocabulary to appear in the translation interface.

Comment: I have done this, but it still does not translate the hierarctical select fields..